# Redirect to url by meta title with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to redirect to a log in page based on the meta title of the page. When logegd out you have a token word "text" and when logged in its same text folloed by a line so something like "text - text".

So i want to redirect towards a page if the logintitle doesnt have the "-" in the title. Is this possible with Javascript or Jquery?

What I have so far:

```
<script>
if(document.title.indexOf("-") == -1) {
window.location.assign(http://link) 
}
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(document.title.indexOf("-") == -1) {
    redirect code
}
```

Comment: You know, I suppose I assumed you had the redirect code ready.  If that's a bad move on my part, let me know...

Comment: Luckily that part's darn easy as well :)
window.location.assign(...);

Comment: And if you are truly starting from scratch I could probably help with the execution as well.

Comment: Would be helpful! Updated my question with what im trying with so far. My Javascript skills arent the best.. :) @whiterabbit24

Comment: You're going to want to put your url in quotes, either single or double.

Comment: And something you're going to have to figure out is when the check/redirect is going to happen.  Javascript works best when you tie it to events.  When you click this button, change the background color.  When you hover over this text, highlight it.  So what's your trigger (it could be as simple as "When the page loads..."), and what do you want to happen when the trigger is tripped (in this case it's your check and shove).

Comment: For me it would be when the page loads, i guess @whiterabbit25

Comment: Okay.  I'm a huge supporter of JQuery.  It's basically just a Javascript library, but it takes a lot of the annoying things about its parent language out of the equation and streamlines the language quite a bit.  It's worth looking into!  So if you don't mind I'm going to switch to that. :)  Add this tag to link to the JQuery library:
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Then, since you're running your code when the document is ready, just put it in here (it's the JQuery document ready function):

$( function() {
    ...
});

Comment: Darn it, I spaced that out on lines and everything.  Forgot comments just wrap...

Comment: Im using this on some wierd buisnessplatform and it already loads jquery, So i dont need to link in that library. Will try the updated code!

Comment: Oh, and if you have the time and inclination to learn a bit of code, I'd recommend checking out Code Academy.  A free signup gets you access to their hands-on lessons in some of the big languages.  I tell people to start with JQuery before you tackle Javascript.  It'll save you some headaches, and if you want to learn what's underneath the hood Javascript is always there for you to look at later on.

Comment: And, of course, don't forget the semicolon at the end of your redirect line.  All Javascript lines need 'em!

Comment: Thanks! Took a look, seems helpful! Reagrding to the script, it now works. one last question - it now redirects to the page if the "-" is missing - if i want it the opposite way.. can i use a plussign instead or is it a different way to do this?

Comment: The indexOf function checks a string for a character and returns a number corresponding to that character's position in said string, starting with 0.  If it doesn't find the character it returns -1.  So if you want to redirect if it does find a hyphen you'd do it if it's NOT equal to -1, or if(document.title.indexOf("-") != -1)

Comment: Alternately you could just say greater than -1 (> -1), but that's just semantics. :)